# How use fscanf to scan a file seperated by commas

Tags: c, scanf, readfile

I am trying to scan the file but not getting the correct output when I print it. Can you explain how fsccanf works when we are trying to read comma seperated files?

```
fscanf(infile,"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%d",l->head->place,&l->head->data->year,&l->head->data->month,&l->head->data->day,&l->head->data->magnitude,&l->head->data->latitude,&l->head->data->longitude,&l->head->data->Tsunami);

printf("%s %d %d %d %lf %lf %lf %d", l->head->place,l->head->data->year,l->head->data->month,l->head->data->day,l->head->data->magnitude,l->head->data->latitude,l->head->data->longitude,l->head->data->Tsunami);
```

[image: I am getting the first and last element correct as read by the file, however fscanf isnt reading other elements of file correctly.]

Comment: The `%[]` format is for strings, and strings only. You attempt to read it into other types, which leads to *undefined behavior*. Furthermore, the `%[]` format doesn't skip leading space, like the newline left over from the previous call to `fscanf`.

Comment: Please edit your question and post your `struct` definition in a separate code block. Also, post a few lines of your input data file in another code block

Comment: maham shaikh, Post an example of the **comma** separated data.

Comment: @maham shaikh, Tip: avoid `fscanf()`.  Use `fgets()` to read a _line_ into a _string_ and then parse the string.  Far easier to handle input errors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want:

```
struct whatever *d = l->head->data;
if( 8 == scanf("%31[^,],%d,%d,%d,%lf,%lf,%lf,%d", 
    l->head->place, &d->year, &d->month, &d->day,
    &d->magnitude, &d->latitude, &d->longitude, &d->Tsunami)
) { ... }
```

Note that the `31` above assumes that `l->head->place` can hold at least 32 chars. Also, this is still subject to undefined behavior on certain inputs, and the format string really ought to be something like: `"%31[^,],%8d,%8d,%8d,%lf,%lf,%lf,%8d"`, but I'm not aware of any defense against the undefined behavior for the `%lf` conversion specifiers, so there's not much point in restricting the `%d` specifiers.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply. So how should I read the whole line and assign exact data to the variables? Because if I assign certain chars to the string, it messes up. Is there a better way to scan my text file separated by commas? example of the line: Country1 2016,11,13,4.9,-42.2914,173.8065,1

Comment: @mahamshaikh It looks like your file is not comma separated.  The sample input (in your comment) does not have a comma after the first word (before "2016").  If that is the case, you need to remove the comma from the format string.  If your input is inconsistent, you will need to add more logic.

Comment: If the sample input you show above is consistent, you could just try `"%31s %d, %d ..."`

Comment: I figured it out, thankyou